# How to download a full web page (css, js and images included) and all linked web pages

Tags: bash, wget

This command gets all the files that are necessary to properly display a given html page.

```
wget --page-requisites http://example.com/your/page.html
```

I want to loop through for all the links on that page ie the `a href`'s and apply the same command (or similar, doesn't have to be bash) to them.

Comment: Does [wget mirror](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Very-Advanced-Usage.html) do what you need?  Or is there more to the requirements?

Comment: @david_adler this not download all necessary things. It doesn't download images used in the html page. Try for this https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html

Comment: except, oddly, no wget command in this whole thread actually downloads all files for offline usage... ‍

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
wget -r -l 2 --page-requisites http://example.com/your/page.html
```

See `man wget`

> Recursive Retrieval Options
>
> ```
>    -r
>
>    --recursive
>        Turn on recursive retrieving.    The default maximum depth is 5.
>
>    -l depth
>    --level=depth
>        Specify recursion maximum depth level depth.
> ```